80s horror film with a man pulling something out of his ear
I once saw a single scene of this horror film from mid- to late-80s where a man is looking in a mirror and feels something in his ear.
He finds something and pulls and then continues to pull what appears to be brain or other tissue out of his ear for some time, gradually getting more and more freaked out.
I've a vague memory of the man looking like Bruce Campbell (95%+ convinced its not him though), or David Naughton (from American Werewolf) but can't spot a film that matches.

Welcome to Movies & TV! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

I'll put up a possibility, but TBH it might not be the only one. If you know any other details, it might help.

You got it @Walt. I remember the thing in the sink now as well.

This sounds like a scene from the horror film Brain Damage (1988).

One morning a young man wakes to find a small, disgusting creature has attached itself to the base of his brain stem. The creature gives him a euphoric state of happiness but in return demands human victims.

You can see the scene here [WARNING: Very Gory] in which the protagonist is imagining he's pulling his brain out of his head in a long string (I suppose he does bear a resemblance to David Naughton). Here's the trailer:




Yep - that's the one. Thanks.

That could be the worst movie ever made.  I love the announcer for the trailer.  Jesus, could they have picked a worse guy to do a horror movie trailer?
